# increase expiry of firebase storage jpeg link ruby

Tags: ruby, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have been using ruby sdk to connect with `FirebaseStorage`, Its working all fine but I need to know how I can increase the expiry of that link, its only giving 1 or 2 minutes of expiry. I am connecting with the bucket as

```
project_id = "wearabe6a"
key_file   = "service-account.json"
storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new project: project_id, keyfile: key_file
bucket  = storage.bucket "wearableeo.appspot.com"
file    = bucket.file file_name
```

and then I am getting the signed URL. which work fine for a few minutes, But how we can increase expiry of that link?

```
file.signed_url
```

Update:

I have been using this gem for cloud storage https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/files.rb

Comment: Whatever generates a signed url determines when it expires.

Comment: right now it's your `require "google/cloud/storage"` who is creating it. Didn't you people added any flexibility to change such things?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  There is a line of code somewhere in your system that creates the signed url, and it's setting the expiration date.  You can read more about signed urls here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Okay I understand you but I am using your own created library for the ruby gem. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/files.rb and its creating doing everything or me, is there any option to change expiry ?

Comment: I don't know in that case.  I've used other libraries for node and java, and they let you specify an expiration.  Perhaps you could log a bug against the ruby SDK?

Comment: I have found the options in Gem docs. thanks

Comment: Hi @JunaidFarooq if the answer from Frank was useful, please accept it.

Comment: Okay, I am accepting the answer though I had found it by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information of available parameters in the [gem documentation for signed urls](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.54.0/google/cloud/storage/file?method=signed_url-instance).

To extend expiration time beyond 5 minutes (the default value) use:

```
require "google/cloud/storage"

storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new

bucket = storage.bucket "my-todo-app"
file = bucket.file "avatars/heidi/400x400.png"
# Expire in five hours.
# 18000 is five hours in seconds.
shared_url = file.signed_url expires: 18000
```